# Can't remember the word for literal setting of the variables

Tags: word-choice, programming

It is programming related.

Well, I have a phrase, something like:

> If the parameter wasn't set ..., the default value should be used.

I can't remember the word people usually use here. Something like "*wasn't set literally*" or "*manually*". It's on the tip of my tongue. Really frustrating.

Comment: Probably *explicitly*.

Comment: OMG. You're my savior! Can you add it as an answer?

Comment: If the parameter wasn't **initialized** / **preset** See also: http://encyclopedia2.thefreedictionary.com/preset+parameter

Comment: This question is better asked on [programmers.se]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual word for setting a variable is ***explicitly***.

> precisely and clearly expressed or readily observable; leaving nothing to implication
>
> [WordNet via [OneLook](http://www.onelook.com/?w=explicit&ls=a&loc=2osdf)]

The default value is [implied](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/implied) (left to implication), where it is not directly expressed.